# Flask-mail not working, not getting any specific error messages

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I developed a blog-like app for my students where they have an option to submit their texts to the instructor for revision and feedback. On clicking the submit button, the app takes the text the student has written in the text box and sends it to me in the body of an e-mail. It worked fine on my computer, but as soon as I uploaded it to the server (which uses cPanel, ugh), it stopped working.

At first I got an error because the gmail account I'd set up for the app did not allow unsafe apps from accessing it, but I have changed that and it seemed to be working fine.

Here is the setup code for flask-mail in my **init**.py file:

```
app.config.update(dict(
    DEBUG = True,
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com',
    MAIL_PORT = 587,
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True,
    MAIL_USE_SSL = False,
    MAIL_USERNAME = 'emailaddress@gmail.com',
    MAIL_PASSWORD = 'password',
))
mail = Mail(app)
```

And here is the actual implementation code in my routes.py file:

```
if form.submit.data:
    textsubmit = form.content.data
    plaintext = BeautifulSoup(textsubmit)
    userid = current_user.id
    msg = Message("Text from {}".format(userid),
                  sender="emailaddress@gmail.com",
                  recipients=["instructoraddress@gmail.com"])
    msg.body = plaintext
    mail.send(msg)
    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
```

Whenever I click the "submit" button, I get an error on the webpage saying "Incomplete response received from application"

The only error message on cPanel says that mail.send(msg) could not be executed, but I have no idea why.

Comment: Those error message might be unrelated to the above code. Maybe your flask setup on the server isn't correct (routing doesn't work). To test this code in a local test environment you can use `sudo python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:25` to setup a local email server.

Comment: To check if your routing is setup correctly comment out all the code except the return and try again. If the error persists post your urls.py (or whatever the routing config in flask is).

Comment: Any chance the hosting company is blocking emails being sent from their servers to reduce the likelyhood of spam?-- if so, using a mail sending service (like Sendgrid) might avoid the block.

Comment: @tobltobs I'll try that, but since I am forced to use cPanel and that thing is nothing but restrictons, I'll see if it lets me

Comment: @Doobeh that's a good point, I'll look into using Sendgrid. Thanks!

Comment: If you really use google account you need to enable **Less secure apps.**
Simple guide can be found [here](https://support.reolink.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003525833-How-to-Allow-Less-Secure-Apps-to-Access-Your-G-mail-Account). But as mentioned by others, better to use something else like Sendgrid.